# Windows 7 Home Premium Family Pack upgrade + Windows Anytime Upgrade to Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, anytime-upgrade

Is an install of Windows 7 Home Premium Family Pack license upgradeable?

Suppose I'm able to install Windows 7 Home Premium on my computer using a Family Pack key. Would I then be able to upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate using the Anytime Upgrade option?

Considering that the Family Pack only uses one key to activate three PCs, what happens when I upgrade one of those computers with Anytime Upgrade?

Would I be able to use the Anytime Upgrade key on all three computers? Or just one computer?

Is upgrading this license key even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Anytime Upgrade to upgrade a single machine.

When using Anytime Upgrade you receive a new product key that works in conjunction with the existing key.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to find out any such information on the Microsoft site.

However, my logic says that the Family Pack is just an economic option for upgrading 3 computers. Once they are upgraded, you may purchase further upgrades for each of the three.

You may further verify the facts in the Family Pack Eula that you have.

Comment: Thanks harrymc.. I don't have the family pack yet, so I have not been able to take a look at it.. Anyway, will update this thread if I find out..