# Can Vista Home be upgraded to Premium?

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Home Premium Family Pack upgrade + Windows Anytime Upgrade to Ultimate](https://superuser.com/questions/71105/windows-7-home-premium-family-pack-upgrade-windows-anytime-upgrade-to-ultimate)

I have Windows Vista Home on my development machine and want to upgrade to Pro. Can I buy just an upgrade to save money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is not possible, because Microsoft Anytime upgrade support from Home to Professional.

[Windows Anytime Upgrade](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/windows/products/windowsvista/buyorupgrade/windowsanytimeupgrade/overview.mspx)

**Better is if you upgrade directly to Windows 7.**